# Custom shaped view with changable icon and text

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-custom-view, shapes

I want to create a custom View like this with changeable text and icon.
I also want to support multiple device screen easily.

[image]

I'll be using a minSdkVersion = 9.

I tried using a RelativeLayout with a rotatable TextView etc, but to support different screen sizes is very difficult, may be I'm going the wrong way to achieve this goal, any better approach?

Comment: You can probably do this with simple `Button`s and custom background images for different states (e.g. pressed vs not pressed). See [state list drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: I don,t want set all thing as background image,I need translate this button texts and change button icons

Comment: 1. Buttons have text. The text doesn't have to be part of the background. 2. The icons inside the button do not have to be part of the background either. You can use [compound drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (you can do this in XML with the `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, etc. attributes)

Comment: it means I must calculate icon size programmatically?

Comment: Not unless you have some specific reason to...

Comment: is there exists button text's rotations? because in the screen I attached exists text rotations

Comment: The screen you attached is a game and it uses a game engine. It does not uses `View` or `ViewGroup`. Only a canvas where the engine draws into.

Comment: Not, the screen created by Photoshop (psd file) ,and I want create it using android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SDP** - a scalable size unit , helped me to solve this problem.

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

for text views please refer to [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) which is based on the sp size unit for texts.

https://github.com/intuit/sdp